# Java Heap Space Error on data insertion over SQL Server

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to insert 2-milliion lines into a SQL Database, and get this error:

> JDBC::error: Java heap space

The insert is a standart *Mathematica* SQL statement:

```
conn = myConn[ip]
columns = {"Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"}
SQLInsert[conn, "MyTable", columns,data]
CloseSQLConnection[conn]
```

Where data is a `List`of 2-million elements (rows). The command works just fine for a smaller number of rows.

I know I could break data into small chunks, but I would like to know how to solve it increasing the Java heap space.

Comment: Like this... http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3791 ?

Comment: @OleksandrR. interesting tks. Do you know how can I know my current heap space?

Comment: @Murta Yes, you can call `JavaLink[]` and then you see in my case `-Xmx256m` which defines the maximum  possible.

Comment: @halirutan strange, when I execute `JavaLink[]` I get: `LinkObject['/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub' -init "/tmp/m000001265201",81,4]`

Comment: Hm, on OSX, everything is different. I guess you have 256MB too. You could check the file `FileNames["InstallJava.m", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]` and search for `-Xmx`.

Comment: I was wondering what the maximum size increase possible for my windows laptop would be? How could I find out to set it to the maximum? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use JVMArguments

```
<<JLink`;
InstallJava[];
ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx512m"]
```

Shameless copy From [Wolfram](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3791) ;-)

Or directly...

```
InstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx512m"]
```

The options available depend on your JVM runtime. The standard way to get the non-standard options is (in the shell) `java -X`

Comment: For Mac use: `ReinstallJava[CommandLine->"java",JVMArguments->"-Xmx512m"];`

Comment: Nice link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1010266/2048848)

Answer (score 0):

2023 update on M1 Mac:

[image]

increase heap space to 1GB

```
<< JLink`;
InstallJava[];
ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx1024m"]
```

increase it to 8GB

```
<< JLink`;
InstallJava[];
ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx8192m"]
```