# JAVA error NoSuchFieldException: usr_paths with OpenSQLConnection after installing 13.2

Tags: windows, java, sql

I performed a fresh install of Mathematica 13.2. The first code that I tried worked just fine under 13.0. It opens an SQL server connection using single sign-on (SSO) for my credentials. However, in 13.2 I got an error that I've seen many times before:

> I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.

This occurs because SSO needs the 'ntlmauth.dll' file to be installed, which doesn't come in a default Mathematica installation. This is easily solved by downloading this file from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/latest/download) and installing it in Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.2\SystemFiles\Java\Windows-x86-64\bin

Usually, I can then proceed without problems, but this time I get this error:

> A Java exception occurred: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: usr_paths

[image]

Anyone got a clue what to do here? The connection seems to work, regardless of this error message, but of course I don't want this error message (and I do not like the option to just throw a `Quiet` on it).

Comment: My SQL code got broken by 12.3 but worked again in 13.1.
Make sure to search for SQL in Mathematica Stack Exchange to see if any of the other issues relate to your issue.   
Some existing are:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41431/opensqlconnection-error?rq=1
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39583/java-heap-space-error-on-data-insertion-over-sql-server?rq=1
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267502/who-broke-the-jdbc
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253551/opensqlconnection-fails-due-to-some-java-problem#comment633794_253551

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this solution yet but Wolfram provided the steps below.  This won't solve the error message but at least they are working on fixing it in a future release.

---

Thank you for letting us know about this. The developers are working to have a fix soon. In the meantime a work around is to do the following:

ne workaround would be adding mssql authentication library location (C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.2\SystemFiles\Links\DatabaseLink\Java\Libraries\Windows-x86-64) to "Path" system environment variable.

Steps:
Go to edit the system environment
Select "Path" System variables.
Click edit button.
Click New button.
Add mssql library path 'C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.2\SystemFiles\Links\DatabaseLink\Java\Libraries\Windows-x86-64'
Click Ok -> Ok -> OK
Restart mathematica

MSSQL_Library_Location: FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","Links","DatabaseLink","Java","Libraries",$SystemID}] //SystemOpen

Note: The connection with be sucessfull but there will be error message.